civictheme is dependent on ckeditor 4 module but it is deprecated
Integrating CivicTheme on Drupal version 9.5.11.
But this theme is dependent on CKEditor-4.

Installed CKEditor-4 version 1.0.2 but it not supported by Drupal.

Integrating Drupal CivicTheme feature on Drupal Version 9.5.11.
All dependency modules are installed and enabled.
In that CKEditor-4 module is the required dependency module. Installed that too. But it is deprecated and also not supported by Drupal.
Reference:
**    Requires Dependency modules list:**
CKEditor 4 (contrib) (disabled)
Components
Custom Block
Configuration Manager
Content Moderation
Datetime Range
Help
Inline Form Errors
Layout Builder
Layout Discovery
Media
Media Library
Options
RESTful Web Services
Shortcut
Taxonomy
Field Group
Layout Builder Restrictions
Linkit
Menu Block
Paragraphs
Pathauto
Redirect
Webform
kindly help me out to resolve this.
